# Flask app localhost is not a valid cookie domain

Tags: python, flask

I need some help troubleshooting this `userwarning` message on my flask app. I am unfamiliar with this territory and couldn't find anything on the internet. The app is running in development mode and I am not using any cookies or sessions in my app. All it does is wait for client-side query to upload data to database. I set in the `config.py`, `SERVER_NAME` equal to `localhost:5000`. What do I need to do to get rid of this warning? Thanks for the help.

```
/miniconda3/envs/rq-redis/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/sessions.py:211: 
UserWarning: "localhost" is not a valid cookie domain, it must contain a ".". 
Add an entry to your hosts file, for example "localhost.localdomain", and use that instead.
' "{rv}.localdomain", and use that instead.'.format(rv=rv)
```

Comment: The full documented answer to your question is in the error text.

Comment: hi, I absolutely know nothing about domains/cookies/networking. I read the warning but have no understanding of it. I read some other somewhat related threads, and tried to change the `SERVER_NAME` to 0.0.0.0; now I am getting: `UserWarning: The session cookie domain is an IP address. This may not work as intended in some browsers. Add an entry to your hosts file, for example "localhost.localdomain", and use that instead`

Comment: Welp looks like you just found a good time to learn about networking! Start with the search terms that were given to you: `hosts file` for instance. On Windows this is `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts`. On Mac and *nix this is `/etc/hosts` (though it's occasionally generated from elsewhere).

Comment: im on a mac; all i see it `127.0.0.1       localhost`, `255.255.255.255 broadcasthost`, `::1             localhost`. Don't know what this means. Should I enter 127.0.0.1 As the `SERVER_NAME`?

Comment: In your Flask config file set SERVER_NAME = "localhost.localdomain:8000" and the warning will go away while you are in development mode. You can change 8000 to another port, if you are using something like 8080, etc. This answer doesn't explain why the warning is coming up, but will allow you to silence it.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to disable the warning by deleting the SERVER_NAME from the config file and use the built-in server which is good for development only.